# How to reduce space between widgets and between blog posts in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm trying to reduce the space above and below the sidebar widgets as well as reduce the space between the blog posts on my Wordpress site, but I can't figure out how. I've searched all over the internet and tried inputting code that worked for other people into both the theme's style sheet and the "Additional CSS" area, but to no avail.

Here is a link to the page so you can see what I'm talking about: https://www.swissarmymusician.com/articles/

If it means anything, I'm using the "Astra" theme (free version).
If anyone could help it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your `style.css`

```
.widget {
padding: 1em .65em; //1st value top/bottom 2nd value left/right; Default was 2em;
margin: 1em .65em; //1st value top/bottom 2nd value left/right; Default was 2em;
}
```

Regards.

Learn more about CSS **units** @ https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp;
Learn more about CSS **padding** @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp;
Learn more about CSS **margin** @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp;

**EDIT 1:** If you want to edit the widget title you can target it with:

```
.widget-title {
margin-bottom: .65em; //Default was 1em;
}
```

Don't hesitate if you need a bit more help.

**EDIT 2** Regarding last comments

```
.widget {
padding: 1em .65em !important; //1st value top/bottom 2nd value left/right; Default was 2em;
margin: 1em .65em !important; //1st value top/bottom 2nd value left/right; Default was 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I put both codes at the bottom of my style sheet, and neither seemed to do anything. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Add the two lines at the bottom of your file, you can add the `!important` statement to override previous behaviour see EDIT 2

Comment: `rem` units are preferred over `em` because of better accessibility for both font-size, margins, etc. Read why here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-rem-vs-em-units

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to learn early on in your life as a website maker to use the devtools in your favorite browser (it's already installed with the browser). If you inspect your sidebar, you will see this and can then easily detect which css class you have to modify in order to make changes:

[image]

Here I'd modify the orange or yellow part at the bottom of the inspected widget `div` so that you either get more padding (yellow inspector color) at the bottom (padding-bottom:) or margin (orange inspector color) (margin-bottom:).

If your styles don't work you may need to add an `!important` flag to each line that doesn't work the traditional way so that your change overwrites the theme's own CSS styles. Best of luck with the site.